# How to show different name user

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 4 tables.

mahasiswa's table have:

| id | user_id | nim |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 112 |

dosen's table have:

| id | user_id | nik |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 001 |
| 2 | 2 | 002 |
| 3 | 3 | 003 |

user's table have:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex |
| 2 | Merlyn |
| 3 | Mark |
| 4 | John |

Lets say bimbingan's table data like this:

| id | mhs_id | dosen_id | types |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 |

In my model, i wrote:

```
        $this->db->select('u.name as name_mhs, s.name as name_dsn, r.name as name_spv, e.name as name_par');
        $this->db->from('bimbingan as b');
        $this->db->join('mahasiswa as m', 'm.id = b.mhs_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('user as u', 'u.id = m.user_id', 'left');

        // for dsn
        $this->db->join('dosen as d', 'd.id = b.dosen_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('user as s', 's.id = d.user_id', 'left');
        
        // for spv
        $this->db->join('dosen as n', 'n.id = b.dosen_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('user as r', 'r.id = n.user_id', 'left');

        // for par
        $this->db->join('dosen as o', 'o.id = b.dosen_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('user as e', 'e.id = o.user_id', 'left');

        $this->db->group_by('b.mhs_id');
        return $this->db->get();
```

but the result showing same name for each dosen's name.

I want the result like this:

| id | Mahasiswa's name | Dosen's name | Dosen's name | Supervisor's name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JOHN | ALEX | MARK | MERLYN |

Comment: Show desired output.

Comment: Presumably mhs_id is the same as mahasiswa.id. I suspect very few non-Indonesian speakers would be aware of this. Play to the room.

Comment: Yea, mhs_id was mahasiswa.id

Comment: I want the output like this:
mahasiswa_name, dosen_name (where type: 1), dosen_name (where type: 2), dosen_name (where type: 3)
@Akina

Comment: Add it into the question text, not as a comment.

Comment: have you tried manipulating the query using group_concat function?

Comment: i'll try it right now

Comment: thanks it work.. but only their id. how to show their names.